# I have a list of JTextField references. Is there any way to initialize those through an array?

Tags: java, arraylist

```
 ArrayList<JTextField> listTxt=new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(
                txtVel1,txtVel2,txtVel3,txtVel4,txtVel5,txtVel6,
                txtVel7,txtVel8,txtVel9,txtVel10,txtVel11,
                txtVel12,txtVel13,txtVel14,txtVel15,txtVel16,
                txtVel17,txtVel18,txtVel19,txtVel20));
```

Is there any way to initialize these JTextField through a loop, or do I need to go one by one?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for something like this:

```
ArrayList<JTextField> listTxt=new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=0; i<20; i++){
    listTxt.add(new JTextField());
}
```

Comment: I dont think so. I already have the list of references listTxt. Now I have to create and assign an object to every single one.

Comment: If you have references then you have objects already. Or do you have some amount of variables and want to assign new objects to them? Then you don't have a list of references but a list of nulls.

Comment: Yeah, I basically just declared those txtVelx as JTextFields, then I added them to the list as above. Now I'm trying to assign objects to those in a loop. Hope it makes more sense what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Then it is not possible to do*. If you want to assign object reference to the variable, you have to call `txtVelx = ...`.  (*In theory it would be possible with reflection, but I'd advice against using it, especially if you don't know what you are doing.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a stream/map operation, though ote that the swing API has a lot of old dinosaurs in there which don't always play nice with the new toys that java 8 brought. Still, this should work:

```java
var textFields = List.of(txtVel1, txtVel2, txtVel3).stream()
    .map(JTextField::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

now `textFields` is a variable referencing a list of JTextField instances, each initialized with one of the strings.

Comment: I'm using a framework specific for the company im working at. It overwrites a lot of stuff concerning swing. This is what I tried to do after making that listTxt ArrayList.
`for(JTextField tf:listTxt){
   tf=SwingUtil.createReadOnlyTextField(45);
  }` 
What if I had to add focus and keylisteners as well. I want all of them to be the same and have the same listeners. This obviously doesn't work as tf variable is just a copy.

Comment: .map(s -> {JTextField tf = SwingUtil.createReadOnlyTextField(45); tf.setText(s); tf.addKeylistener(myKeyListener);}) – instead of the map call I showed in this answer.